# Meteor does not run - exit code 8 + unable to allocate arraybuffer

Tags: meteor

I am trying to run Meteor on my computer and it does not work.
I get the exit code 8 + another error about not being able to allocate arraybuffer.

The error details are way too long for me to put everything here...

Do you have any ideas how to solde it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add any useful information like your OS, which version of meteor are you trying to install, the exact error message...

Comment: (ok sorry it's my first time on stackoverflow I do not have this reflex yet.) I am working on Windows 7 (64 bits), I've just updated Meteor so it is the last one (and I also had the error message before). I cannot put the whole error message details as it is way too big. All the problems seem to come from files used for MongoDB. But the main mistake is : "exited with code 8" , and "unable to allocate to arraybuffer." It is perfectly working on my colleagues' computer.

Comment: Here is the beginning of the error message (too long..) : ' C:\Users\Clarisse\Desktop\profileBuilder-dev>meteor [[[[[ C:\Users\Clarisse\Desktop\profileBuilder-dev ]]]]] => Started proxy. => Exited with code: 8 W20150804-14:23:47.976(1)? (STDERR) W20150804-14:23:47.980(1)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Clarisse\AppData\Local\.meteor\pack ages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\f ibers\future.js:278 W20150804-14:23:47.980(1)? (STDERR) throw(ex); W20150804-14:23:47.980(1)? (STDERR) ^ W20150804-14:23:47.980(1)? (STDERR) MongoError: auth failed '

Comment: I'm not familiar with Meteor, but seems that someone is having the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079682/exited-with-code-8-sample-meteor-applications


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420304/meteor-exited-with-code-8-error

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this person does not exactly have the same problem. His problem came from his code. Whereas I cannot launch meteor to continue developping our app, but all my colleagues can, and we have the same files so it is not the code.

Comment: The very last line of the stack trace says `MongoError: auth failed`. Sounds like a connection string issue connecting to your mongo instance.

Comment: Did you check if you have more than 4gb free on your computer? It does not seem to be related to your issue, but it is a mongo limitation that can trigger weird messages on startup. Worth a check.

Comment: @BrianShamblen : if this is an authentification problem, why would my colleagues not have the same problem?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet : I have 1Go available for my RAM, and 307 Go available on my computer in total. This is not enough?

Comment: @Clarisse D lol I guess it is. I just said what came to my mind. Make sure your mongo version is compatible. Maybe run a `meteor update`, it might be the difference with your collegues (or they use an older version of meteor, not compatible with mongo 3+) Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872655/3793161

Comment: @ClarisseD Can you connect to mongodb through the cli, using the same connection information as the app? If not, the port may be blocked by your  firewall.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet : I have already done an update, and I already had the erros before.